# Find outliers in time series with unknown distributions

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I want to detect outliers in time series data like the two outliers in the image below.
At first I tried LOF, which didn't work well and outlier detection methods based on normal distributions wouldn't work.

The detection method should detect an observation as an outlier when there is an untypical change in the time series.

Any suggestions what would be a good approach?

(I am using R so far btw.)

[image]

Comment: You could use a rolling window and always look at the observations around your centre point. Compute eg the average difference between the observations around your centre and if the difference between the centre and the nearest point is let's say at least twice the difference of the values around it, it's an outlier. You only have to be careful with your jumping points.

Comment: The jumping points are the main problem i know, but arent there any methods that can learn the normal behaviour and can detect abnormal observations afterwards?

Comment: Define abnormal ;) You could always look at a certain window and compute the moments of these observations, then for example create confidence intervals.

Comment: Is it a valid approach to add lagged versions of the time series and run for example LOF (local outlier factor) of that multivariate dataset? The idea is to detect outliers like the second one by considering the predecessor of the observation. But I haven't found anything about that method where lagged variables are included, is there some reason?

Answer (score 2):

Your time-series looks similar to ion fluxes through single channels. If that is the case then you should probably look for well-established methods that take into account the physics and biochemistry of the system under study. Statisticians can help a bit, but you may be asking them to re-invent the wheel.

Maybe an approach like that described here would be good: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258530467_Idealizing_Ion_Channel_Recordings_by_a_Jump_Segmentation_Multiresolution_Filter

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach:

- The one on the top is easy, you just put a threshold $t$ (e.g. at t=15) on the data itself, i.e. you discard any points that have a value $y_i > t$.
- The other one can be caught with a threshold on the first order difference of the points, since it is several times further away from its neighbours than all the other points. That means you would discard any points that have a value $d_i = | y_i - y_{i-1} | > t$. This would also catch the first error.
- The second idea can be extended to the comment of tho_mi, where you would not only calculate $d_i$ but $\left | y_i - \sum_{j = i-10}^{i+10} y_j \right|$, i.e. the difference between $y_i$ and a running average around it.

Comment: Your first two approaches might run into problems, since the data fluctuates more later.

Comment: I dont want to set any hardcoded threshold to detect the first outlier. i was hoping that there is some more generic approach maybe available as a r package.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but just for future users, one way can be to develop an XMR/SPC process control chart, and implement some rules, such as if a data point is 1/2/or 3 sigmas away from the moving average, it can be considered an outlier. Similarly, if consecutive points fall outside of sigma range, that group of points can be considered anomalies.

XMR charts have been used heavily to analyse process variability and stability.